# Hitting maxsize issues for canvas element on iOS for small canvas

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm working on a whiteboard app (JS/HTML) which uses a canvas element wrapped with fabric.js.

I'm aware of certain [size limitations](https://www.xspdf.com/help/50953786.html) with the canvas element, however I'm scratching my head as to why to why my canvas fails to render at all on iOS even at relatively small sizes of 2300 x 1200 pixels.

I've prepared a small demo below. On my iPhone XS this only renders the grey div, no canvas. If I drop the canvas size down to say 1500 x 1200 it works.

This is at odds what this [canvas size capability checker](https://on690.codesandbox.io/) tells me which states my phone being capable of a 4096 x 4096 pixel canvas.

```js
// create a wrapper around native canvas element (with id="c")
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

// create a rectangle object
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  fill: 'red',
  width: 60,
  height: 60
});

// "add" rectangle onto canvas
canvas.add(rect);
canvas.setBackgroundColor('rgba(255, 73, 64, 0.6)', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.3.1/fabric.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.0.2/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="m-10 bg-gray-400 w-3/4 h-64 overflow-x-auto overflow-y-auto">
  <canvas id="c" width='2300' height="1200"></canvas>
</div>
```

Any pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've now worked out that fabric creates a canvas at twice the configured size on retina screens which means that a configured width of 2300px for the fabric object actually results in a canvas of 4600px width which in turn exceeds the device capabilities.

What I still don't know is how to work around this so that I can create a larger canvas on some iOS devices such as my phone which declares a capability of 4096x 4096px.

The added complexity is that we share the canvas in realtime between different devices so one screen may be retina and one may be standard resolution.

Comment: Any luck with this?